# How to access layout elements of one activity file in another activity file in android

Tags: android

I have 3 tabs (like whatsapp) and they load same webview(which is defined in activity_main.xml) but in the bottom I want to load a relative layout in tab2(which is defined in android_fragment.xml). Unfortunately when I access that element using FINDVIEWBYID its showing nothing not even an error message.

So I am confused. Is it possible to call layout elements of activity file in another activity file using findviewbyid or is there any other way to do it ?

```
     MainActivity.java
     public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    MainFragment mainFragment=      (MainFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    if(mainFragment==null){
        Log.d("MAIN FRAME IS NULL", "RETURNING ");
        return;
    }
    String value = tab.getText().toString();
    Log.d("TAB VALUE", value);
    if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("tab1")) {
        mainFragment.executeJavascriptFunction("tab1()");
        //webview.loadUrl("javascript:tab1();");

    } else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("tab2")) {
        System.out.println("Inside Tab2");
        imageButton.setVisibility(0);
        editText.setVisibility(0);
        /*txtview.setVisibility(0);*/
    /*mainFragment.executeJavascriptFunction("tab2()");
        {
         edit=  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Log.d("Value of Editext", edit.toString());
    edit.setVisibility(0);
        }

        //webview.loadUrl("javascript:tab2();");
        */
    } else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("tab3")) {
        mainFragment.executeJavascriptFunction("tab3()");
        //webview.loadUrl("javascript:tab3();");
        imageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

Comment: can you put some code of your activity or class ?

Comment: Are you really using different activity for each tab?

Comment: Yes you can include your 2nd xml in 1st xml
<include
            layout="@layout/android_fragment"/>

Comment: It seems like, from the name, you are using fragments, which I would recommend. Or a TabPager or something.

Comment: Thanx @sunit sunny it worked but withsome sideeffects...on click of tab2 it comes but it remains on the screen on click of other tabs also... I have set imageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);editText.setVisibility(View.GONE); on click of tab3 but now i stopped coming on click of tab2 also

Comment: I have uploaded my code also...